# PHP website search

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

I'm having trouble getting my php search project working properly, having followed a guide, I don't fully understand the guide/code. My search bar will allow me to search for jobs in the database, but currently it shows all jobs and filters the one you search.

Is it possible to display these jobs as links, where it will take you to another page and display the currently selected job.

Here is my current code:

```
<?php
    require 'config.php';
    if(isset($_POST['search']))
    {
        $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
        // search in all table columns
        // using concat mysql function
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `job` WHERE CONCAT(`location`, `description`, `budget`, `duedate`,`title`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
        $search_result = filterTable($query);

    }
     else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `job`";
        $search_result = filterTable($query);
    }

    // function to connect and execute the query
    function filterTable($query)
    {
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bid4myjob");
        $filter_Result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        return $filter_Result;
    }

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>PHP HTML TABLE DATA SEARCH</title>
            <style>
                table,tr,th,td
                {
                    border: 1px solid black;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>

            <form action="php_html_table_data_filter.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="Value To Search"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"><br><br>

                 <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Location</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Budget</th>
                        <th>Due date</th>
                    </tr>

          <!-- populate table from mysql database -->
                    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['title'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['location'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['description'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['budget'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['duedate'];?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endwhile;?>
                </table>
            </form>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please use PDO instead of mysql_* or mysqli_* Methods.

Comment: You haven't explained your issue. "making it fully work" is not an actual issue you're having. Compare it to taking your car to the mechanic and go "something is wrong whenever i drive" instead of "the back of the car rattles when i reach >60 mph".

Comment: Is it not possible with mysql?

Comment: I did say the problem, Currently it is displaying the whole job table and when i search it just filters results.What I am trying to do is have just a search bar that will display the results

Comment: Can you include an example of what it does?

Comment: If you want to display jobs as a link, you should create a template and pass the current job to the template, which will access and populate the template based on the job selected.

Comment: Also - be sure to sanitize your input(s)

Comment: Yes so far i have followed this guide and it does this https://youtu.be/2XuxFi85GTw?t=7m48s

Comment: i just want the search bar at the start then for the output to be displayed after the search

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: Also, **Never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly. If your tutorial didn't explain either of these things (parameterisation and mysql user setup ) it's inadequate, and arguably irresponsible.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
if(isset($_POST['search']))
```

There's no variable called "search" which will be submitted by your form, so its value will never be set, and this `if` block will never be entered. I suspect you've confused the "name" attribute which determines the variable's name in the POST array, with its value ("Search", in the case of your button). Try

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

instead.

See also my comments above about your security problems and aim to fix those a.s.a.p.